# How to find australian zip codes using regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I am working on an RoR project, where I want to find a valid Australian zip code from a string. My string is as follows:-

```
"[\"\", \"\\\"ParsedText\\\":TVR \", \"PURCHASE \", \"TOTAL \", \"APPROVED \", \"05/02/18 20.51 \", \"TOTAL \", \"EFT \", \"CHANGE \", \"Taxable Iteus \", \"TOTAL includes GST \", \"OTHER SAVINGS \", \"Woolworths \", \"fresh people \", \"VICTORIA PARK PH: (08) 6318 9975 \", \"Your Store Manager is: Mark \", \"Your Assistant Store Manager is: Nick \", \"Your Customer Service Manager is: Taylar \", \"Let us know how can make your shopping trip better \", \"WOOLWORTHS INVOICE - ABN 88 OOO 014 675 \", \"$34.44 \", \"CARO:.............0553 T \", \"$0.00 \", \"$0.75 \", \"22.65 \", \"*SMITHS CRINKLE PERI PERI 150G \", \"SUNRICE BASMATI IKG \", \"NESTLE MILO POUCH 150G \", \"INGHAM BREAST 400G \", \"*BULLA CREAMY CLASSICVANILLA 21 \", \"DON HAM LEG SHAVED ENGLISH BAKEO 250G \", \"GOLDBELGlANCHOCOLATELAVACAKE2PK180G \", \"CHOBANI GREEK YOG BLUEBRY NON FAT 170G \", \"Qty \", \"$2.25 ea \", \"3 \", \"CHOBANI GREEK YOG MANGO FAI I?OG \", \"Qty \", \"$2.25 ea \", \"3 \", \"CHOBANI GREEK YOG BLACK CHERRY 170G \", \"Qty \", \"2 \", \"$2.25 ed \", \"CHOBANI GREEK YOG STRAWB BANANA 170G \", \"Oty \", \"2 \", \"$2.25 ea \", \"CHOBANI GREEK OFFER \", \"17 SUBTOTAL \", \"WOOLWORTHS \", \"VICTORIA PARK \", \"4333 \", \"MERCH ID: 611000606004333 \", \"TERM ID. \", \"\\\"4333088 \", \"Bankwest Credit CREDIT \", \"AIO \", \"A0000000041010 \", \"ARQC \", \"7EB518169AOB56E? \", \"0000000000 \", \"$34.44 \", \"$34.44 \", \"00 \", \"002366 \", \"3.29 \", \"4.20 \", \"2.00 \", \"4. Iff \", \"5.00 \", \"2, BOA \", \"3.00 \", \"6.75 \", \"6.75 \", \"4.50 \", \"4.50 \", \"-12.50 \", \"$34.44 \", \"$34.44 \", \"Thank'S for pi Cking \", \"Total Savings $ 22.65 \", \",\\\"ErrorMessage\\\":\\\"\\\",\", \"\\\"ErrorDetails\\\":\\\"\\\"\", \"},\", \"],\", \"\\\"OCRExitCode\\\":\\\"1\\\",\", \"\\\"IsErroredOnProcessing\\\":\\\"false\\\",\", \"\\\"ErrorMessage\\\":\\\"null\\\",\", \"\\\"ErrorDetails\\\":\\\"null\\\",\", \"\\\"ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds\\\":\\\"1.735\\\",\", \"\\\"SearchablePDFURL\\\":\\\"Searchable PDF not generated as it was not requested.\\\"\", \"}\"]"
```

I tried two patterns as follows:-

```
mystring[/(0[289][0-9]{2})|(0[89][0-9]{2})|([1-2]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{2})|(2[9][0-1]{1}[1-4]{1})|([3-7]{1}[0-5]{1}[0-9]{2})|([7-9]{1}[8-9]{1}[0-9]{2})/]
```

And:

```
mystring[/\d{4}/]
```

But both patterns return invalid zip codes. As my string contains a phone number `(08) 6318 9975` so it returns the first four numbers `6318`, which is an invalid zip code. The correct zip code in my string is `4333`. Please help me to find the valid zip code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will the zip code text always be formated like this?  `\"4333 \"`

Comment: yes the format is same

Comment: Do you want the very first valid zip code, or all the zip codes?

Comment: There will be only one valid zip code rest will be any numbers. i want the valid zip code

Comment: Autralian zip code always be a four digits number but my string might contains some other four digits numbers.

Comment: have you tried  `mystring[/\\"\d{4}\\"/]`  that looks like it should capture that exact field when the 4 numbers are by themselves.

Comment: It returns nil.

Comment: I think you can use `mystring[/VICTORIA PARK\s*",\s*"(\d+)/, 1]`

Comment: I can't  use 'VICTORIA PARK' as this is not fixed

Comment: Then what is the rule? How can you define the context, rule for extraction?

Comment: There can be any text any four digits number but i have to find only the valid australian zip codes

Comment: Then it is impossible since any 4 digit numbers that match the AUS ZIP  will match your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for help will try diffrent approach...is there any gem which can provide list of australian zip codes?

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
(?<!\d |\d)\d{4}(?= ?\\)
```

[example](https://regex101.com/r/Gt7Xms/1/) explanation on upper right corner of the page

or this

```
(?<=\")\d{4}(?= ?\\)
```

[example](https://regex101.com/r/Gt7Xms/2/) explanation on upper right corner of the page

Note: to implement in ruby escape the special chars (i don´t know Ruby may be true may be false)

```
mystring[/(?<!\d |\d)\d{4}(?= ?\\)/]

mystring[/(?<=\")\d{4}(?= ?\\)/]
```

Comment: It returns nil.

Comment: Could you call `JSON.parse` on that string first, to reduce all the excessive `\\\"` marks?

Comment: it also returns 6318 from a phone number  (08) 6318 9975

Comment: it seems ruby have some restrictions on lookbehind :(